# CSS Vertically Centered for print layout

Tags: css, printing

I'm trying to vertically center a div with a image and some nested divs with text in them. (to create a cover page)

The CSS is needed for the print format. I have something like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        <img src="banner.png">
        <span>some title text</span>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="pageBreak">new page...</div>
```

css

```
 @media print {
    .wrapper {
       position:fixed;
       top: 50%;
    }
    .pageBreak {
       page-break-before: always;
    }
}
```

Although perhaps irrelevant, I'm using foundation for a css library.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah i figured it out after a lot of trial and error...and gaining a better understanding of relative vs absolute with nested divs

I have

```
@media print {
  .coverPage { // outerDiv
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    page-break-after: always;
  }

  .coverPageWrapper { // innerDiv
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```